# Facebook login button - how to check if we're logged in before attempting to login?

Tags: javascript, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login, loginstatus

I'm trying to use the facebook javascript SDK to let my app connect to the user's facebook account.

Is there a simple way to check if my app is already connected to facebook before running the code to connect it? It has to reload the page so the user can actually see that they are logged in through facebook, but if I do location.reload(); at the end it will go into an infinite loop because this code is in the header and it will run again. The header is on every page so redirecting to somewhere else won't help.

The js code to make a facebook login button work, mostly from facebook's step by step guide:

```
<script>
function statusChangeCallback(response) {
    console.log('statusChangeCallback');
    console.log(response);
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
        testAPI();
    } else {
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML = 'Please log ' + 'into this app.';
    }
}

window.fbAsyncInit = function () {
    FB.init({
        appId: '(my app id)',
        cookie: true,
        xfbml: true,
        version: 'v2.8'
    });

    FB.getLoginStatus(function (response) {
        statusChangeCallback(response);
    });

};
(function (d, s, id) {
    var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
    if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
    js = d.createElement(s);
    js.id = id;
    js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/debug.js";
    fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));

function testAPI() {
    console.log('Welcome!  Fetching your information.... ');
    FB.api('/me', function (response) {
        console.log('Successful login for: ' + response.name);
        document.getElementById('status').innerHTML =
            'Thanks for logging in, ' + response.name + '!';
    });
    get_fb_info();
}

function get_fb_info() {
    FB.api('/me', 'GET', {fields: 'first_name,last_name,name,email,id,picture'}, function (response) { //add email,
        console.log("FB NAME: " + response.name);
        console.log("FB EMAIL: " + response.email);

        data_string = 'fb_id=' + response.id + '&f_name=' + response.first_name + '&l_name=' + response.last_name + '&name=' + response.name + '&email=' + response.email + '&picture=' + response.picture;
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "ajax_fb_login.php",
            data: data_string,
            success: function (data) {
                console.log(data);
                //location.reload(); only has to happen once
            }
        })
    });
}
</script>
```

Thanks :)

Comment: Add `status: true` in your FB.init parameters, so that the SDK actually checks the current login status.

Answer (score 4):

Based on the official documentation, something like the following should do the trick:

```
FB.getLoginStatus(function(response) {
  if (response.status === 'connected') {
    // the user is logged in and has authenticated your
    // app, and response.authResponse supplies
    // the user's ID, a valid access token, a signed
    // request, and the time the access token 
    // and signed request each expire
    var uid = response.authResponse.userID;
    var accessToken = response.authResponse.accessToken;
  } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
    // the user is logged in to Facebook, 
    // but has not authenticated your app
  } else {
    // the user isn't logged in to Facebook.
  }
 });
```

FB.getLoginStatus() allows you to determine if a user is logged in to Facebook and has authenticated your app. There are three possible states for a user:

1. the user is logged into Facebook and has authenticated your
   application (connected)
2. the user is logged into Facebook but has not authenticated your
   application (not_authorized)
3. the user is either not logged into Facebook or explicitly logged out
   of your application so it doesn't attempt to connect to Facebook and
   thus, we don't know if they've authenticated your application or not
   (unknown)

Comment: I tried that, but i get an error "Uncaught ReferenceError: FB is not defined"

Comment: Where exactly are you trying to call the FB object? Can you update your original code with the logic to get the login status?

Comment: I want to put the whole code that i have in my post inside the else block, so that it doesn't bother doing anything if it's already connected. I also tried to put it inside window.fbAsyncInit = function () {}, but then it said Object {status: "unknown", authResponse: null} and didn't really work either

Comment: The only thing that I can imagine is that you are trying to do calls to the FB object before it's even loaded. Maybe check how you are loading the javascript library and check if you have an actual FB object defined and not null, after having that and maybe after the page has been loaded and fully rendered, run your validation with FB.getLoginStatus.

Comment: So I need to load FB right before checking the login status. The code to do that must be somewhere in code i posted above because I'm using FB in that code, but i can't figure out which part... My guess was FB.init, but that doesn't seem like it since it itself needs FB to be loaded.